# Split with consecutive delimiters AND empty last character

Tags: c++, split, delimiter, c-strings

I am currently struggling with making this split function work correctly.

What I need:

The function must split the String that contains delimiters (:) into a List (called ListaPos).

Cadena is a class that makes working with chars easier.

For example:

---

Example 1)

1:Josh:Scott::1995:

Should add to a list (1,Josh,Scott,@EMPTY@,1995,@EMPTY@)

My current functions are giving me this output: (1,Josh,Scott,@EMPTY@,1995)

---

Example 2)

1:Mike::

Should add to a list (1,Mike,@EMPTY@,@EMPTY@)

My current functions are giving me this output: (1,Mike,@EMPTY@)

Here are the functions being used at the moment:

```
char* strtok_single(char* str, char const* delims)
{
    static char* src = NULL;
    char* p, * ret = 0;

    if (str != NULL)
        src = str;

    if (src == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if ((p = strpbrk(src, delims)) != NULL) {
        *p = 0;
        ret = src;
        src = ++p;

    }
    else if (*src) {
        ret = src;
        src = NULL;
    }

    return ret;
}

ListaPos<Cadena>* Cadena::Split(Cadena& str, const char* delimitador) const {
    Cadena empty = Cadena("@EMPTY@", true);
    ListaPos<Cadena>* ret = new ListaPosImp<Cadena>();
    char* p = strtok_single(str.GetNewCharPtr(), delimitador);

    while (p) {
        Cadena nueva = Cadena(p, true);
        if (nueva == empty)
        {
            cout << "ERROR: No se puede agregar la tupla, no se puede insertar el dato @EMPTY@.";
            delete ret;
            return NULL;
        }
        if (*p)  ret->AgregarFin(p);
        else     ret->AgregarFin("@EMPTY@");
        p = strtok_single(NULL, delimitador);
    }
    return ret;

}
```

If you could help me achieving my goal, I would appreciate it very much.

Thank you all.

Comment: Avoid that `static` variable, harder to test, no re-entrency, ...

Comment: Run your program with just ":" as the input. Use a debugger to step through this code, one line at a time, in order to observe where the logic fails, and see the simple logical flaw, and the obvious fix, then fix it. Mission accomplished, wasn't this easy?

Comment: What is `ListaPos`?  Why not simply a  `std::vector<std::string>` to hold the results?  *Cadena is a class that makes working with chars easier* -- why have that, when there is `std::string`?

Comment: If you just use `std::string` then you can use `std::getline()` with an `std::istringstream` instead of this strtok hack.

Comment: Cadena is a class that we are forced to use in this project. ListaPos is a list that cointains Cadenas.
I really tried a lot of things, but I can't seem to get to a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to understand what the function Split does. Nevertheless the function `strtok_single` has a logical error in this part

```
else if (*src) {
    ret = src;
    src = NULL;
}
```

There should be

```
else 
{
    ret = src;
    src = NULL;
}
```

Here is a C demonstrative program (for the demonstration of using the standard C function `strpbrk` there is not necessary to use a C++ program)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* strtok_single(char* str, char const* delims)
{
    static char* src = NULL;
    char* p, * ret = 0;

    if (str != NULL)
        src = str;

    if (src == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if ((p = strpbrk(src, delims)) != NULL) {
        *p = 0;
        ret = src;
        src = ++p;

    }
    else 
    {
        ret = src;
        src = NULL;
    }

    return ret;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "1:Josh:Scott::1995:";
    const char *delim = ":";

    for ( char *p = strtok_single( s, delim ); 
          p != NULL; 
          p = strtok_single( NULL, delim ) )
    {
        if ( *p ) puts( p );
        else puts( "@EMPTY@" );
    }         

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1
Josh
Scott
@EMPTY@
1995
@EMPTY@
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the mistake. It's now working flawlessly!